# Sharepoint 2013 Auto Increment Column

Tags: calculated-column, auto-increment

I've read a bunch of articles on how to do this, but I haven't succeeded in making this work.  So I have SP Designer 2013, but due to my Gov. restrictions, I can only utilize 2010 workflows.  I'd like to only utilize Calculated fields within my list if possible.  So here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm using InfoPath for forms.  So when a user fills out and submits a form, it populates within my list.  These Change Requests (which is what the forms are) require an alpha-numeric number that updates each time one is submitted.  I need the column to read "CR Number", and the information within the cell to read CR-001, CR-002, CR-003, etc.

I know this is probably a very easy fix, but I'm new to SharePoint...so please forgive my ignorance.  Would someone please be so kind as to walk me through this?

Thank you so much.

Chris

Comment: Here is an article which might help:https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-auto-increment-column-in-sharepoint-list/

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked perfectly!